# Converting string to number

Tags: macros, environments

I am trying to write an environment which provides (some of) the functionality parallel environment through tabular syntax so that the following two code snippets would give equivalent results:

```
\begin{Parallel}{4cm}{5cm}
\ParallelLText{TEXT 1}
\ParallelRText{TEXT 2}
\end{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}
```

(*usual* syntax above)

```
\begin{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}{p{4cm}p{5cm}}
TEXT 1 & TEXT 2
\end{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}
```

So far, I've got the following code, which works:

```
\NewEnviron{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}[1]{%
  \StrFindGroup{#1}{1}[\dimL]
  \StrFindGroup{#1}{2}[\dimR]

  \def \textL {\StrBefore{\BODY}{&}}
  \def \textR {\StrBehind{\BODY}{&}}

  \begin{Parallel}{0.5\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
    \ParallelLText{\textL}
    \ParallelRText{\textR}
  \end{Parallel}
}
```

However, I would like two write the code below to use the arguments given by the user, but this gives the error ! Missing number, treated as zero. I guess the cause for this is that the digits in the string \textL is threated as letters and not as digits. How do you make LaTeX/TeX treat the digits as digits?

```
\NewEnviron{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}[1]{%
  \StrFindGroup{#1}{1}[\dimL]
  \StrFindGroup{#1}{2}[\dimR]

  \def \textL {\StrBefore{\BODY}{&}}
  \def \textR {\StrBehind{\BODY}{&}}

  \begin{Parallel}{\dimL}{\dimR}
    \ParallelLText{\textL} % Problematic rows
    \ParallelRText{\textR} % ----------------
  \end{Parallel}
}
```

Comment: It isn't that they are treated as letters it is that the `\StrBefore` isn't an expandable command so it is a sequence of `\def` and other instructions that would typeset as digits if typesetting but can not be used in an assignment, like `\setlength\foo{\def\zz{1pt}\zz}` does not work to set `\foo` to `1pt`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can I use some other package instead of xstring to avoid this problem? I.e. is there any expandable alternative to \StrBefore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. When you do

```
\StrFindGroup{#1}{1}[\dimL]
```

the expansion of `\dimL` is `{4cm}` and not `4cm`. So you have to strip off those braces. It's more efficient to extract the two parts in advance, too. Don't forget to expand `\BODY` or the `&` wouldn't be scanned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{xstring,environ}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usedim}[1]{\expandafter\@firstofone#1}
\makeatother

\NewEnviron{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}[1]{%
  \StrFindGroup{#1}{1}[\dimL]%
  \StrFindGroup{#1}{2}[\dimR]%
  \expandarg % <-- you need to expand \BODY or the & isn't scanned
  \StrBefore{\BODY}{&}[\textL]%
  \StrBehind{\BODY}{&}[\textR]%
  \begin{Parallel}{\usedim\dimL}{\usedim\dimR}
    \ParallelLText{\textL}%
    \ParallelRText{\textR}%
  \end{Parallel}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}{p{4cm}p{5cm}}
TEXT 1 & TEXT 2
\end{ParallelWithTabularSyntax}
\end{document}
```

In alternative to the trick with `\usedim` you can change the `\begin{Parallel}` line with

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\begin{Parallel}\dimL\dimR}\x
```